# Install package that result of a local build of another angular project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli-v6

I'm migrationg all my projects from angular 5 to angular 6. I have some projects that dependes on anothers.

I have a project, lets call `ProjectA` that dependes on `ProjectB`. I make a build for the `ProjectB` that results on a group of files on the folder `dist`.

Usually, when I want to test, I take the files from the folder `dist` from the `ProjectB` and put on `ProjectA` under the folder `node_modules`. Basiclly I'm making a "manual" instalation of the package `ProjectB`.

The problem on this scenario is that, when I make `npm install`, it will be install the latest version of `ProjectB` and the manual instalation of `ProjectB` will be losed.

What are my options for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found out on [this post](https://medium.com/@the1mills/how-to-test-your-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-1c4cb4b369be) that you can run the following command, and the npm will install local package build as a could package:

> npm install /absolute/local/path/to/your/other/package

**Important note:**

Pay attention to your `package.config`, because it will be change after installing on this way, for the package that you install using the absolute path folder.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of angular-cli v6 "Library" concept. Migrate your `ProjectB` as an Angular Library project, your `ProjectA` as a regular project, and maintain them together. Read the following introductory article to get a better idea:

[The Angular Library Series - Creating a Library with the Angular CLI](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5)

If you have to maintain A & B as 2 separate repositories, you can add your ProjectB as a GIT submodule for your ProjectA and put it into the correct place. Then use it as a Library project.